# Decodificar json que devuelve arreglos u objetos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, gson

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación en Android que funciona con ws. El punto es que un ws contiene un campo que cuando está vacío lo reconoce como arreglo

```
"linked_accounts": []
```

Pero cuando este campo contiene información me devuelve un objeto así:

```
"linked_accounts": {
            "1": {
                "user": {
                    "id": 2152,
                    "external_id": null,
                    "email": "jose8@gmail.com",
                    "iku_email": null,
                    "iku_username": null,
                    "iku_password": null,
                    "remember_token": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "is_iku_member": false,
                    "is_customer": true,
                    "payment_customer_id": null,
                    "device_uuid": null,
                    "phone_number": null,
                    "linked_accounts": ",2149",
                    "avatar_url": null,
                    "people": {
                        "id": 2216,
                        "name": "José 8",
                        "first_name": "José",
                        "last_name": "8",
                        "gender": null
                    }
                }
```

El problema continua al declarar este campo en mi modelo Java, ya que si lo tengo declarado como arreglo y el usuario tiene cuentas asociadas, me arroja error (debido a que el campo linked_accounts espera un array pero se obtiene un objeto), y viceversa si el usuario no tiene cuentas asociadas. Podría alguien ayudarme? De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Deberías poner el código con el que tomas el JSON (string) y lo conviertes a objetos para poder ayudarte.

Comment: lo correcto en este caso seria cambiar el ws, de manera que cuando no tenga datos te devuelva un array vacio, y cuando tenga datos devuelva un array de objetos, en este caso de objetos user. Como tal no tiene sentido una propiedad "1" (de hecho no se si deberia interpretarse como error)

Comment: Me parece que tu mejor alternativa, asumiendo que no se puede corregir el ws, es usar jackson u org.json que te permiten procesar el feed nodo a nodo inspeccionando si se trata de un objeto o de un array.

Comment: Es importante agregues el código como menciona RockoDev, de esta forma se podría ayudar de una mejor forma revisa [ask].